# android crop image: start selection should be full screen by default without fixed ratio

Tags: android, android-intent

Hello I have implemented a image cropping feature for android and it works fine. However I want to set the default rectangle of the selection in cropping mode to full screen at first but the user should be able to change the cropping selection without any fixed ratio.

How can I implement it?

I use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
```

to create the right intent. By default the selection is centered in the image and have some space to the edges if I do it this way. Like here:

[image: cropping centered example]

I have tried it with giving some extras to the intent like here but it doesnt solved my problem:

```
intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: "using the default android tools" -- there are no "default android tools". "I use `Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");` to create the right intent" -- that `Intent` is not part of Android. [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html).

Comment: sorry for my bad explanation i've edited my question.